# Emulate perl's md5_base64 function in javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, md5

Could you please suggest a way to get in javascript the same result as perl's `md5_base64` function does? My current js environment has `md5` and `base64encode` functions, but I'm not sure how to use them on the right way.

I've tried to write something like this, but result differs from perl's:

```
function hex2str(str) {
    var res = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
        res += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return res;
}

var md5res = md5('test'); // '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'

var token = base64encode(hex2str(md5('test'))); // got 'CcKPa8ONRiHDk3PDisOeTsKDJifCtMO2'
```

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Digest::MD5 qw{md5_base64};

print md5_base64("test"); // 'CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g'
```

Comment: Please show the output of `md5('test')` from your JS code.  Your `hex2str` function appears OK - for you to get the correct output the MD5 should be `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` and I've confirmed that `window.btoa(hex2str('098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6))` results in the same output as your Perl code.

Comment: Yes, md5 output is '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6', added to code. Looks like `base64encode` returns wrong result.

Comment: Because of UTF-16 encoding, your `hex2str` function is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `md5()` and `base64encode()` separately.

The output of the former *should* be `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`. 
If you are running in a browser you should also be able to use `window.btoa()` as a Base64 encoder function.

I've separately verified that `window.btoa(hex2str('098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'))` produces the same output as your Perl code (except that `window.btoa` includes some `==` padding on the end to make the output a multiple of 4 bytes long, per the Base64 spec).